# Get selected rows and columns with jQuery Selectable plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-selectable

I'm using the jQuery ui Selectable plugin. It's working perfectly fine and all, but the next thing I need is to get the length of the selected rows and columns. I will use these numbers with jQuery .attr to group the selected cells together with colspan and rowspan.

```
firstCell = $(".ui-selected").first().attr("id");
$("#"+firstCell).attr({"colspan": <dynamic number columns>, "rowspan": <dynamic number rows>});
```

HTML code is generated dynamically with jQuery:

```
$("#div1").empty()

var RH = $("#RH").text();

if(RH) {

    $("#div1").css("display", "block");

    var html = '<table class="rack" style="border=0; cellspacing=0; cellpadding=1; width: 100%;"><thead><tr></tr></thead><tbody id="selectable">';
    html += "<tr><th width='10%'>&nbsp;</th><th width='20%'>Front</th><th width='50%'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Interior</th><th width='20%'>Back</th></tr>";

    for (var i = RH; i >= 1; i--) {

        html += '<tr>\
                    <th>'+i+'</th>\
                    <td id="r'+i+'c1" class="atom state_F r'+i+'c1">\
                        <div title="Free rackspace">&nbsp;</div>\
                    </td>\
                    <td id="r'+i+'c2" class="atom state_F r'+i+'c2">\
                        <div title="Free rackspace">&nbsp;</div>\
                    </td>\
                    <td id="r'+i+'c3" class="atom state_F r'+i+'c3">\
                        <div title="Free rackspace">&nbsp;</div>\
                    </td>\
                </tr>';
        }


    html += '</tbody></table>';
    $(html).appendTo('#div1');
}
```

How would I let jQuery ui selectable return amount of rows/columns selected?

Comment: show us your HTML code please.

Comment: are you using jquery ui selectable or something else..?

Comment: yes, i'm using jquery ui selectable.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem by substracting the id of all the selected < td >'s in 2 parts. One part is the amount of uniquely selected rows and one part is for the amount of uniquely selected columns. I then used those number values as dynamic values at the line with the .attr attribute.

```
$("#selectable").selectable({
    filter: 'td',
    stop: function () {
        loop = 0;
        var rowList = Array();
        var columnList = Array();

        var result = $("#select-resultSpan").empty();
        $(".ui-selected", this).each(function() {
            var index = $("td").index(this);
            result.append("<li>" + $(this).attr("class") + "</li>");    
            var selectedID = $(this).attr("id");
            var row = selectedID.substr(0, 3);
            var column = selectedID.substr(3);

            rowList.push(row);
            columnList.push(column);

            if(loop == 0) {
                firstCell = $(".ui-selected").first().attr("id");
                $("#"+firstCell).removeClass("atom state_F");
                $("#"+firstCell).addClass("atom state_T");  


                $(".ui-selected").not($("#"+firstCell)).remove();

                loop += 1;
            }
        });

        var uniqueRows = ($.unique(rowList).length); // dynamic rowspan value
        var uniqueColumns = ($.unique(columnList).length); // dynamic colspan value

        $("#"+firstCell).attr({"colspan": uniqueColumns, "rowspan": uniqueRows});   

        $("#addObject").css("display", "block");
    }

});
```

I hope this helps someone else as well in the future.